# Работа с setinterval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

У меня есть конпка по которой я включаю и выключаю подрузку картинок

```
  const [rep, setRep] = useState(false);

 
  var idInterval;
  const onRepeatClicked = () => {
    setRep(!rep);
    idInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (!rep) {
        dispatch(getCat());
      }else{
        clearInterval(idInterval);
      }
    }, 2000);
```

Если я нажимаю чек бокс, то срабатывает onRepeatClicked и картинки начинают подгружаться каждый 2 сек, но если я выключаю чек бокс ,то они так же продолжают загружаться, я очищаю интервал, но почему-то затем срабатывает диспатч, подскажите в чём проблема?

Comment: В общем я решил проблему таким образом, что я не использую переменную rep из локального стейта, я просто проверяю e.target.checked если тру то диспатчу, если фалс, то клир интервал, но подскажите это нормально ли, это вроде не по flux, я же должен сначала сохранять в стейт данные и оттуда их брать? Допустимо ли такое решение?

Comment: А с rep у меня была проблема следующая, если сейчас rep = false я нажимаю на чекбокс соответственно e.target.checked становится true, а  rep всё ещё false, ему видимо нужно время, а точнее перезагрузка какая-то, по идее мне бы хотелось использовать именно rep из стейта, но что-то не получается, может подскажет кто?

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `useEffect` подписаться на изменение `rep` и в зависимости от значения удалять/запускать интервал.

Пример на [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gaueyp)

```
const [rep, setRep] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
let interval;
if (rep) {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('dispatch');
  }, 2000);
}
return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [rep]);

return (
<div>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    onChange={() => setRep((prevState) => !prevState)}
    checked={rep}
  />
</div>
)}
```